# Network not reachable on both virtual machines

Tags: virtual, vmware

I have installed VMware Workstation for a while now. Today, I wanted to use one of my virtual machines(Ubuntu) ,but I have faced a problem:"network unreachable". I opened my second machine too and the same problem. I don't understand why the internet does not work on my virtual machines, considering the fact that on the host machine everything is great. I have NAT connections.

Comment: Are you running it on windows (host)?

Comment: Yes. windows 10

Comment: Check if your NAT services are UP, also try disabling the firewall on Windows

Comment: Still ,it doesn't work :(